# Tunneling through SSH for 1521 port access?

Tags: ssh, php, tunnel, ssh-tunnel, oracle-11g

I am developing locally on my computer, using my own Apache server with PHP configured.

My database however is remotely located on an Oracle 11g Database Server. We were also given a separate remote server for hosting our `.html` and `.php` files, however only FTP access has been provided there. Development is far too slow waiting for the FTP connection to push.

So I decided to develop locally, but still use the remote DB server. Unfortunately that gives me [**an error**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Dw8Ns/show/).

Not sure how—or where—to integrate tunnelling.

**Do I add something to the [`oci_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) `HOST` in my PHP file, or do I encapsulate my whole environment over SSH?**

Comment: Unless you can get an SSH connection to the remote DB server, you will not be able to tunnel via SSH. What access do you have to the remote DB server?

Answer (score 1):

This message says oci_connect is **undefined function**. I don't see how would this be related not only to tunneling, but to IP connectivity at all.

For oci_connect, you need:

- PHP 5
- PECL OCI8 >= 1.1.0
- Oracle Client binaries (on your machine), minimum suggested is basiclite Oracle Instant Client.

Are you sure you comply?

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.requirements.php